# Sqlite3 if user_id already in database

Tags: sqlite, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a ranking system for my discord server. However, it keeps adding the user-id into the table even though the user-id is already in there. I've tried something, but that didn't help.

Code:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message): 
        conn = sqlite3.connect('levels.db')
        curs = conn.cursor()

        curs.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GUILD_{message.guild.id} (user_id int NOT NULL, exp int DEFAULT 0, lvl int DEFAULT 0)""")    
        for user in message.guild.members:
            if user.bot != True:
                curs.execute(f"INSERT INTO GUILD_{message.guild.id} (user_id) VALUES ({user.id})")
        conn.commit()

        if message.author.bot != True:
            try:

                curs.execute(f"SELECT * FROM GUILD_{message.guild.id} WHERE user_id={message.author.id}")
                result = curs.fetchone()
                print("found")
                if result[1] == 25:
                    embed_var = discord.Embed(title="", description=f"{message.author.mention.lower()} is now level {result[2]+1}", color=0xffffff)    
                    await message.channel.send(embed=embed_var)
                    curs.execute(f"UPDATE GUILD_{message.guild.id} SET exp=0, lvl={result[2]+1} WHERE user_id={message.author.id}")    
                    conn.commit()  
                else:
                    curs.execute(f"UPDATE GUILD_{message.guild.id} SET exp={result[1]+1} WHERE user_id={message.author.id}")    
                    conn.commit()  

            except sqlite3.OperationalError:
                pass
```

Attempt:

```
        if message.author.bot != True:
            try:
                curs.execute(f"SELECT EXISTS(SELECT user_id={message.author.id})")
                if curs.fetchone():
                    curs.execute(f"SELECT * FROM GUILD_{message.guild.id} WHERE user_id={message.author.id}")
                    result = curs.fetchone()
                    print("found")
                    if result[1] == 25:
                        embed_var = discord.Embed(title="", description=f"{message.author.mention.lower()} is now level {result[2]+1}", color=0xffffff)    
                        await message.channel.send(embed=embed_var)
                        curs.execute(f"UPDATE GUILD_{message.guild.id} SET exp=0, lvl={result[2]+1} WHERE user_id={message.author.id}")    
                        conn.commit()  
                    else:
                        curs.execute(f"UPDATE GUILD_{message.guild.id} SET exp={result[1]+1} WHERE user_id={message.author.id}")    
                        conn.commit()  
                else:
                    print("fuck")

            except sqlite3.OperationalError:
                pass
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `UNIQUE` constraint in your `user_id` column. The constraint makes sure that there aren't any two rows with the same value in the column it's applied in. Since you already have a `NOT NULL` constraint in it, you can use `PRIMARY KEY` on your `user_id` column instead, which is a combination of both `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL`.
After that, you can add `OR IGNORE` after `INSERT` in your insert statement (`INSERT OR IGNORE INTO GUILD_{message.guild.id} (user_id) VALUES ({user.id})`), which will skip the insertion if the id is already in the database.
You should probably do this setup outside of on_message, like maybe in the `__init__` of your cog, and in [`on_member_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_join).
Also, you should use an async library for your database, like [asqlite](https://github.com/Rapptz/asqlite) or [aiosqlite](https://pypi.org/project/aiosqlite/), as sqlite3 is [blocking](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean)